# Example where law of large numbers does not hold

Tags: random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that

$X_n = n $ with probability $\frac{1}{2n \log(n)}$

$X_n = -n$ with probability $\frac{1}{2n \log(n)}$

$X_n = 0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n \log(n)}$

Let S := $X_2 + ... + X_{n+1}$.

I got the hint to consider the events $A_n = \{ |X_n| = n \}$ and to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma. I should consider what happens to $| \frac{S_n}{n}|$ under the event $A_n$.

Why, in this case, the law of strong numbers does NOT hold?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The usual statement of the law of large numbers applies to i.i.d. variables, which is not what you have here -- the variance is not the same for all the $X_n$.  What statement of the (strong, weak, other) law of large numbers are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got the hint to consider the events $A_n = \{ |X_n| = n \}$ and to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma. I should consider what happens to $| \frac{S_n}{n}|$ under the event $A_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel–Cantelli lemma hint suggests considering something like $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n}{n}\right| \ge 1\right)$

$P\left(\left| \frac{S_n}{n}\right| \ge 1\right) =\mathbb P\left(\left| {S_n}\right| \ge n\right) \ge \frac12 P\left(\left| {A_n}\right| \ge n\right) = \frac12 \frac{1}{n \log_e(n)}\ge \frac12 \int\limits_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x \log_e(x)}\, dx$, since we might either add $n$ or subtract $n$ from whatever value $S_n-A_n$ takes and at least one of those $A_n=\pm n$ events will make $\left| {S_n}\right| \ge n$

So $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n}{n}\right| \ge 1\right) \ge \frac12 \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty  P\left(\left| {A_n}\right| \ge n\right) \ge \frac12 \int\limits_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x \log_e(x)}\, dx = \infty$.

Since the $A_n$ are independent we can use the [converse of the Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) to conclude that almost surely among the $A_n$ the necessary $\pm n$ occur infinitely often and so $\left| \frac{S_n}{n}\right| > 1$ infinitely often.

So the strong law of large numbers does not apply: $\frac{S_n}{n}$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thanks a lot for the good explanations! :)

Comment: What does $P(|A_n|\geq n)$ mean? $A_n$ is defined by OP as an event.

Comment: @Snoop - a good question about something from 19 months ago. It seems I may have mixed up $X_n$ and $A_n$